# Classification using ctree in R

Tags: r, cart, precision-recall, confusion-matrix, sensitivity-specificity

I've been trying to perform classification on Indian Liver Patients Disease dataset available at https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/ILPD+(Indian+Liver+Patient+Dataset)

I have used Conditional Inference Tree function from party package in R.

```
ilpd_ctree <- ctree(Class ~ .  ,data=train)
ilpd_ctree
plot(ilpd_ctree)
treepre <- predict(ilpd_ctree,test)
confusionMatrix(test$Class,treepre)
table(treepre,test$Class)
```

The problem is I am not getting any entries in the second class as a result of which Specificity and Pos. Pred. Value are coming out to be NA. However, I want numeric quantities for both of these. How do I attain it on the same dataset?

```
Data from a part of the dataset

structure(list(age = c(65L, 62L, 62L, 58L, 72L, 46L, 26L, 29L, 
17L, 55L), gender = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), 
TB = c(0.7, 10.9, 7.3, 1, 3.9, 1.8, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.7), 
DB = c(0.1, 5.5, 4.1, 0.4, 2, 0.7, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.2), Alkphos = c(187L, 
699L, 490L, 182L, 195L, 208L, 154L, 202L, 202L, 290L), SGPT = c(16L, 
64L, 60L, 14L, 27L, 19L, 16L, 14L, 22L, 53L), sgot = c(18L, 
100L, 68L, 20L, 59L, 14L, 12L, 11L, 19L, 58L), TP = c(6.8, 
7.5, 7, 6.8, 7.3, 7.6, 7, 6.7, 7.4, 6.8), ALB = c(3.3, 3.2, 
3.3, 3.4, 2.4, 4.4, 3.5, 3.6, 4.1, 3.4), AG = c(0.9, 0.74, 
0.89, 1, 0.4, 1.3, 1, 1.1, 1.2, 1), Class = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("One", "Two"
), class = "factor")), .Names = c("age", "gender", "TB", 
"DB", "Alkphos", "SGPT", "sgot", "TP", "ALB", "AG", "Class"), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")


Result

Confusion Matrix and Statistics

      Reference
 Prediction One Two
        One 124   0
        Two  49   0

           Accuracy : 0.7168          
             95% CI : (0.6434, 0.7825)
No Information Rate : 1               
P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 1               

              Kappa : 0               
Mcnemar's Test P-Value : 7.025e-12       

        Sensitivity : 0.7168          
        Specificity :     NA          
     Pos Pred Value :     NA          
     Neg Pred Value :     NA          
         Prevalence : 1.0000          
     Detection Rate : 0.7168
```

Detection Prevalence : 0.7168
      Balanced Accuracy :     NA

```
   'Positive' Class : One
```

The problem is the Pos. Pred. Value which comes down to NA.

Comment: If there is a statistical question here, then please share enough information about the data and the results for us to help you with it.

Comment: @whuber Done with results and data addition.

Comment: Usually "fitting this model results in strange and confusing errors" is a good indication that "this model is a poor fit to the data."

Comment: @ssdecontrol that's what my question is, how to improve this fit?

Comment: Also, often when I have issues like this it's because I did something silly and left a variable in the data set that shouldn't have been there. With only a sample of your data, it's very hard to say what might be wrong. (I'm not asking you to post all of it obviously)

Comment: Is that confusion matrix the one from your test data set? The problem is not that the model isn't predicting anything in the second class on the test set, it's that the test data set doesn't have any observations in the second class!

Comment: @ssdecontrol Yes it's from my test data, I don't know how but nothing from the second class goes

Answer (score 0):

This looks like not to be a good solution as you have no cases predicted in your test data in your class two- are your classes very imbalanced on your train data to start with? if Yes, you might want to find a way around it ( i.e downsampling)- Trees can perform very  poorly on imbalanced data...

but if you want to calculate the specificity of your current model manually: 0/49 =0

Comment: No they are pretty well balanced on the train data.